# DataMapper validation errors with brackets

Tags: ruby, validation, sinatra, ruby-datamapper

I'm using DataMapper's validations, but I can't get the error messages text :(

I tried:

```
@error = user.errors.first
@error = user.errors.full_messages.first
@error = user.errors.full_messages.flatten
@error = user.errors[0]
```

But still I get an array :(

In my template I have

```
- if @error
  %p.lead= @error
```

And I get `["This username is taken"]`

If I have

```
- if @error
  - @error.each do |er|
    %p.lead= er
```

it works, but isn't there a way to send only a string to the template and it to work with the `%p = @error` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `@error` is an array, which it seems to be, then that's how it will show up.

What you probably want is:

```
@error = user.errors.full_messages.flatten.join(', ')
```

Something like that will collapse it to a string. `flatten` returns an Array.

Comment: Use to_sentence, it's prettier in both its signature and its output.

Comment: Thank you very much! :) (as for `to_sentence` I'm using Sinatra :) )